# Polygon is not closed

Tags: java, android, google-maps, polygon

Help, I'm trying to draw a polygon, my polygon is not closing and my coordinates are correct. One last point doesn't connect with the others to form the polygon. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. Thanks

[image: screenshot]

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;

import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ZoomButton;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import android.app.AppOpsManager;


 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
 import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
 import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
 import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polygon;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolygonOptions;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

  import java.util.Map;


 public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements   OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedinstancestate) {
    super.onCreate(savedinstancestate);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMaps);
    final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMaps2);
    final Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMaps3);
    final Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMaps4);
    final Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMaps5);
    final Button button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMaps6);
    final Button button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMaps7);
    final Button button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMaps8);
    final Button button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMaps9);
    final Button button10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMaps10);


    button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    button4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    button5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    button6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    button7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    button8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    button9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    button10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            mMap.clear();
            if (button1.isShown()) {

                Polygon polygon = mMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
                        .add(new LatLng(6.519,3.368),new LatLng(6.520,3.376), new LatLng(6.522, 3.378), new LatLng(6.523,3.382), new LatLng(6.524,3.390), new LatLng(6.524, 3.999),new LatLng(6.523, 3.406),new LatLng(6.520, 3.404),new LatLng(6.518, 3.406),new LatLng(6.516, 3.407),new LatLng(6.511, 3.409), new LatLng(6.509, 3.410),new LatLng(6.504, 3.410), new LatLng(6.501, 3.407), new LatLng(6.497, 3.402),new LatLng(6.494, 3.399),new LatLng(6.492, 3.397),new LatLng(6.487, 3.397),new LatLng(6.484, 3.398),new LatLng(6.481, 3.396),new LatLng(6.477, 3.395),new LatLng(6.475, 3.395),new LatLng(6.472, 3.395),new LatLng(6.468, 3.394),new LatLng(6.467, 3.387),new LatLng(6.463, 3.381),new LatLng(6.467, 3.379),new LatLng(6.468, 3.377),new LatLng(6.469, 3.374),new LatLng(6.468, 3.370),new LatLng(6.467, 3.365),new LatLng(6.472, 3.364),new LatLng(6.475, 3.365),new LatLng(6.478, 3.366),new LatLng(6.479, 3.367),new LatLng(6.481, 3.369),new LatLng(6.481, 3.372),new LatLng(6.481, 3.376),new LatLng(6.480, 3.381),new LatLng(6.482, 3.384),new LatLng(6.519,3.368))
                        .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
                        .geodesic(true));

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.5084, 3.3842)).title("Lagos Mainland").snippet("My Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)));
                button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button9.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button10.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: can you put a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polygon is drawed correctly.
The problem is in the point *new LatLng(6.524, 3.999)*. If you add Marker for each LatLng you can watch it.

Try this and hope it helps.

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.524, 3.999)).title("E"));

mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.519,3.368) ).title("P01"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.520,3.376) ).title("P02"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.522, 3.378)).title("P03"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.523,3.382) ).title("P04"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.524,3.390) ).title("P05"));
//Point far
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.524, 3.999)).title("P06")); //point far

mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.523, 3.406)).title("P07"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.520, 3.404)).title("P08"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.518, 3.406)).title("P09"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.516, 3.407)).title("P10"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.511, 3.409)).title("P11"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.509, 3.410)).title("P12"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.504, 3.410)).title("P13"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.501, 3.407)).title("P14"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.497, 3.402)).title("P15"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.494, 3.399)).title("P16"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.492, 3.397)).title("P17"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.487, 3.397)).title("P18"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.484, 3.398)).title("P19"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.481, 3.396)).title("P20"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.477, 3.395)).title("P21"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.475, 3.395)).title("P22"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.472, 3.395)).title("P23"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.468, 3.394)).title("P24"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.467, 3.387)).title("P25"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.463, 3.381)).title("P26"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.467, 3.379)).title("P27"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.468, 3.377)).title("P28"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.469, 3.374)).title("P29"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.468, 3.370)).title("P30"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.467, 3.365)).title("P31"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.472, 3.364)).title("P32"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.475, 3.365)).title("P33"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.478, 3.366)).title("P34"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.479, 3.367)).title("P35"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.481, 3.369)).title("P36"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.481, 3.372)).title("P37"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.481, 3.376)).title("P38"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.480, 3.381)).title("P39"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.482, 3.384)).title("P40"));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(6.519,3.368) ).title("P41"));
```